# Am I understanding how to calculate a mule's pulling capacity correctly?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, animals, vehicles, encumbrance

Am I understanding how to calculate a mule's pulling capacity correctly?

The PHB offers a few bits of information scattered across the chapters, and though [I've read answers like this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71402/what-is-the-cargo-capacity-of-a-cart-versus-a-wagon/71407#71407), I'd like to make sure I'm understanding how to account for a mule's Beast of Burden trait correctly.

A [mule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mule) is a Medium creature with a Strength score of 14, and it has the Beast of Burden trait:

> The mule is considered to be a Large animal for the purpose of determining its carrying capacity.

The [rules on carrying capacity and the amount creatures can pull](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#LiftingandCarrying) state:

> **Carrying Capacity.** *Your carrying capacity is your Strength score
>   multiplied by 15.* This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry,
>   which is high enough that most characters don't usually have to worry
>   about it.
>
> **Push, Drag, or Lift.** You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up
>   to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score).
>   While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity,
>   your speed drops to 5 feet.
>
> **Size and Strength.** Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny
>   creatures can carry less. *For each size category above Medium, double
>   the creature's carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or
>   lift.* For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

And finally, to see how that is affected by the vehicle they are pulling, the rules on [mounts and vehicles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#MountsandVehicles) state:

> An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move
>   weight up to **five times its base carrying capacity, including the
>   weight of the vehicle.** If multiple animals pull the same vehicle, they
>   can add their carrying capacity together.

If I am correctly understanding how to put that together, the carrying capacity of a mule is:

(((Carrying Capacity) x Large creature modifier) x vehicle mount calculation) - weight of vehicle

= (((Strength 14 x 15) x 2) x 5) - [200 lbs (cart) or 400 lbs (wagon)]

= ((210 x 2) x 5) - [200 lbs or 400 lbs]

= (420 lbs x 5) - [200 lbs or 400 lbs]

= 2,100 lbs - [200 lbs or 400 lbs]

Thus, a mule carrying a cart can carry 1,900 lbs, or 1,700 lbs for a wagon (like Minman and Salteris said in the linked question).

Or, is a vehicle considered "pulling an object" and thus has to have an additional calculation:

((((Carrying capacity) x Large creature modifier) x pulling modifier) x vehicle modifier) - weight of vehicle

= ((420lbs x 2) x 5) - vehicle weight

= (840lbs x 5) - vehicle weight

Thus, a mule would be able to carry 4,000 lbs in a cart or 3,800 lbs in a wagon, but would have a 5-foot speed decrease.

Side Question: If this is the case, does the effect negate if two mules are pulling the wagon?

Though I believe it's the first, I'd like to make sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It can pull a vehicle weighing up to 2100 lbs.

The weight limits for pulling a vehicle and dragging an object are both multiples of carrying capacity. Due to the mule's Beast of Burden trait, its carrying capacity is 2 × 15 lbs × Strength = 420 lbs.

In this case the animal is pulling a vehicle, so the limit is 5 × carrying capacity = 2100 lbs for the vehicle and its contents combined.

Speed reduction for pushing/dragging a heavy object only applies for the more general pushing/dragging rule, so the mule gets its full speed when pulling a wagon. Wheels, man. They're actual magic.

(Note that the speed reduction for a heavy object is not a "5-foot speed decrease"; your speed becomes *5 feet*, unless it was already less than that.)

Comment: Might be worth noting that the PHB specifically states in the references provided, "5 times its base **carrying capacity**" which clearly implies that you use your **carrying capacity** for the equation, not the push, drag or lift feature.

Comment: Ah ok, I totally misunderstood the push/drag part.  Thanks for that clarification.