# Are there any creatures that are small (short) and could be a good at pulling a carriage?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am making an armored carriage that is used to transport important people safely. The carriage has two compartments with the bottom compartment containing the creatures (currently horses) and the top part containing the passengers and driver. The problems with such a carriage is handwaved (the fact it is too tall and top heavy, the fact the horses would need to be very well trained to walk into what they see as a wall, etc) but it is also limited by trying to keep it in the realm of possibility.

I want to expand the carriage by putting a turret into the top to put in a magical gun, but the height required to do so makes the carriage tall and goofy looking beyond my ability to suspend my disbelief. Since most of the height comes from the horses I have been trying to find better (smaller) creatures that could be used to pull the carriage. They would need to be smaller than a horse (something around 3 feet tall would be best, but I will take what I can get) and be able to pull the same amount or more.

Edit: It was suggested to add more specific requirements for the needed creatures, so here they are:

- Smaller (in height) than a horse (medium or smaller preferred)
- Can pull an ornate or armored carriage (600 - 1000 lbs) with no more than 4 creatures
- Can pull the carriage at a speed of 40ft or faster
- Need to be safe enough that the average caravan driver could handle them

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "good"? I mean, a team of goblins would be "good" at moving a carriage. Not likely to do so, but they can.

Comment: I think if a 'measure' of good could be established the question might have more merit. A bulleted list of something like 'Is small/medium category, can climb/other features' might help.

Comment: @Jihelu What should go in the list? I can see the speed, size, and pull weight being important, anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need a smaller size category? It seems your concen is about the creatures height. There may be creatures with less body hight in the same size category that fit your needs.

Comment: It also would be good to indicate who is operating the carriage, how dangerous the creatures can be, if you are looking for natural beasts or fantastic creatures, etc.

Comment: Your carriage weighs less than 4 heavily armed adventures inside it probably do

Answer (score 5):

### Let's do some math

We'll assume worse case scenario of 1,000 lbs for the carriage.

Maximum 4 creatures, so each creature needs to be able to "move" 250 lbs.

### But how do they move the carriage?

There are two methods; push or pull. And each of these have very different computations. So how would these creatures be attached to the vehicle?

When we think of pulling, the puller is out in front of the vehicle (horse before the cart). That also means that your engine is exposed to the elements (and enemy fire). It might be possible to hook up some harness that attaches to the rear axle and thus "pull" the carriage. I'll leave that engineering up to you.

If we look at [Mounts and vehicles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/equipment#MountsandVehicles) in the PHB we see that:

> An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle. If multiple animals pull the same vehicle, they can add their carrying capacity together.

And for [Carrying capacity]:

> Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don’t usually have to worry about it.

So that means 250 lbs divided by 15 for carrying capacity, then divided by 5 for pulling. So each creature needs a minimum strength of 3.3 or rounded to 4. Or said the other way, with a strength of 4, times 15 for carrying capacity, times 5 for pulling capacity equals 300 lbs each creature can pull.  That's not too hard to muster. In fact, **too simple**.

Unfortunately, D&D Beyond lacks the search filters to pull this off but other non-linkable sites do.

### You could legally have 4 goats (Strength of 12) pull your 1,000 lbs carriage

Actually, you could get away with just two goats with room to carry a few hundred extra pounds.

If you go the "push" route, then we can't do that final 5x math.

So it would be 250 lbs divided by 15 for carrying capacity... and that's it. For a minimum Strength requirement of 16.6, or rounded to 17. Of which, there are no beasts that are either Small or Medium and have a walking speed of at least 40'. If we say any creature is fair game, then you're looking into training dragons, fiends, aberration, or a few fey.

### So depending on your engineering and level of belief suspension it's either crazy easy, or impossible.

Comment: Hi @MivaScott, it is an optional rule but if you use the Alternative Encumberance rules (which are way more realistic, otherwise encumberance/load is just a joke), then for the creatures to be able to move their full speed, they can only carry 5 lbs per point of STR.  This results in better numbers, see my answer under "Small Options"

Comment: Also, are you aware of the Beast of Burden feature that effectively doubles Strength for Mules? This gives you a medium sized creature that could pull the full weight of the carriage, even under more realistic encumberance.

Answer (score 0):

## There are several options

Note: for my answer I will assume that you use the more stringent and more realistic "Variant: Encumberance" rules (p. 176 PHB), since your question suggests you care about such things.

> If you carry weight in excess o f 5 times your Strength
> score, you are encumbered, which means your speed
> drops by 10 feet. If you carry weight in excess o f 10 times your
> Strength score, (...) you are instead heavily encumbered, which means your speed drops by 20 feet (...)

Encumberance limits in the core rules without this optional rule are purposely set *extremely lenient*, as many play groups do not enjoy tracking encumberance, and with these high limits there is less chance for it to matter. If you do not use *Variant: Encumberance*, you can triple all the numbers in my answer for final weight that can be pulled, and pretty much any kind if medium creature will do.

### How much can they pull?

As per the vehicle rules in DMG, p. 155:

> An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle. If multiple animals pull the same vehicle, they can add their carrying capacity together.

with Base Carrying Capacity under normal encumberance being (p. 176 PHB):

> Carrying Capacity. Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don’t usually have to worry about it.

Assuming you use *Variant: Encumberance*, a creature *at full speed* can pull a loaded vehicle weighing its Strength score x 5 x 5 = Strength score x 25. Four creatures can pull a vehicle weight of their Strength score x 100 lbs.

Some creatures also have the [Beast of Burden](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mule#content) feature, for example the **Mule**:

> **Beast of Burden**: The mule is considered to be a Large animal for the Purpose of determining its carrying Capacity.

> **Size and Strength**. Larger Creatures can bear more weight(...). For each size category above Medium, double the creature’s carrying Capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift.

Four beasts of burden would be able to pull a carriage weighing 200 lbs. times their Strength score.

### How heavy is the loaded carriage?

A normal carriage as per DMG already weighs 600 lbs. You say it will contain a driver and "important people", which sounds like more than one additional person. If we merely assume a weight of about 150 lbs per person with clothing, three people would already add 450 lbs, pushing the total to 1,050 lbs, over the target 1,000 lbs.

You describe your carriage as "ornate or armored" which likely would add another few 100 lbs, and that is before accounting for possible cargo. You might want to consider a larger pull target of something between 1,500 and 2,000 lbs, so that up to four passengers and cargo would fit comfortably.

### Medium Sized Creature Options

If you are looking for beasts that have a real-world history to be trainable: [**Mastiffs**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mastiff) are medium sized, are listed in the pack and riding animals section in the PHB, and have speed 40. Dogs have precendent pulling vehicles, for example sled dogs. Their [overall height](https://www.dimensions.com/element/mastiff) matches the 3 feet you ideally would like. By the rules, 4 of them would fit in the space of a large creature like a horse, and would be able to pull about **1,300 lbs** at full speed.

[**Ponys**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pony) and [**Mules**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mule) also are only medium size, have speed 40, are pack and draft animals with even better strength than Mastiffs, listed in the PHB. In addition, Mules have the **Beast of Burden** feature, so they can [pull twice as much](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/am-i-understanding-how-to-calculate-a-mules-pulling-capacity-correctly). But they may be to tall for your taste? A small Pony would be about [four feet shoulder](https://www.deephollowranch.com/horse-height/). Four **Ponies** could pull a carriage of **1,500 lbs**, four Mules could pull one of **2,800 lbs**.

For more fantasy flavor, you could also use [Boars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/boar), or domesticated pigs, or, as [suggested by](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/are-there-any-dnd-5e-creatures-that-are-small-short-and-could-be-a-good-at-pul/196019#196019) [MivaScott](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/38834/mivascott), [Goats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/goat), although by rules mechanics, they do not offer any advantages over Mastiffs (the goats are also weaker) and they lack the Beast of Burden of Mules. There is also no historical precedent of them being good draft animals.

**Constructs**: (*If you like to stick strictly to prepublished materials, you can ignore this section.*) Of course, if you are not limited to real-world animals, and if you already put magical guns into the top, you can easily also put a magical construct into the bottom to make this cart move, and make up its form and stats, or equip it with magical tank-like chain belts. **Helmed Horrors** are strong and only medium size, and you could reskin their stats for a four legged version. If all you care for is movement, remove their attacks and fly speed for higher speed (they only have 30).

### Small Sized Creature Options

Small creatures technically need a 5x5 space just like medium creatures and therefore do not provide an advantage over them, unless you want to house-rule that more of them can fit in.

The options for this in the MM are rather slim. No natural beasts fit the bill. You could use fiends like the **Dretch**, **Manes**, or **Spined Devil**, magical constructs such as the **Flying Sword** or a monstrosity like the **Darkmantle**. Most of them are also pretty anaemic in strenght and could just pull about **1,000 lbs**. (Darkmantle 1,600 lbs). Further, none of them would seem to satisfy the added requirement of being safe for common caravan drivers who likely would be scared by them.

Potentially you could employ **[Deep Gnomes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/deep-gnome-svirfneblin)**, which have Strength 15 and are good aligned, four of them could pull a cart weighing **1,500 lbs**. If you go down that route, you could also look to  hire four extra-strong Halflings or Gnomes without the underdark weirdness.